# Create Docker Service within Docker Service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is it possible to spawn Docker Services within a container running on Docker swarm? This would allow containers to dynamically maintain the components running in the swarm.

Currently I am able to run containers within other containers on the host machine by mounting the /var/run/docker.sock into the container while using the docker-py SDK.

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock master
```

Inside the container I have a python script that runs the following:

```
container = docker.from_env().containers.run('worker', detach=True, tty=True, volumes=volumes, network='backend-network', mem_limit=worker.memory_limit)
```

Is something similar to this possible in Docker Swarm, not just vanilla Docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount the Docker socket and use the docker module as you're doing now, but create a service, assuming you're on a manager node.

```
some_service = docker.from_env().services.create(…)
```

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/services.html